# Is in this case "you" valid to refer to men?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, pronouns

We have this discussion in a board. A man was talking and he said this

> The theory states that women have higher attractiveness level in their most fertile years 18-25 while men 26-35. In short we are "Late Bloomers". But still you need to improve yourself mentally, financially & emotionally

The guy, with "you" was refering to men. I'm from another country and I understood it right. Then a girl thought he was refering to her and took it in the wrong way like "you" refered to her, and that the guy was telling her to improve. Then the guy clarified, but the girl is still convinced this is gramatically wrong and than you can't use "you" to mean "men" (in this case) because that is gramatically wrong. is it? Can you give an explanation if it is gramatically valid to use "you" to refer to yourself when talking and not to another person?

Comment: You should ask her why she thinks that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase, "while men 26-35." is unfinished. I think it should have been:

> The theory states that women have *a* higher attractiveness level in their most fertile years (18-25) **than** men (26-35). In short we are "Late Bloomers". But still you need to improve yourself mentally, financially & emotionally.

The *we* in "we are 'Late Bloomers'" refers to men, because *late* would refer to the later aged group.

While *you* in the next sentence is unclear as to which gender it applies to,  the "Late Bloomers" seem to have a disadvantage (the advice on what to do), so I believe *you* in the last sentence refers to men.

To be clear, the last sentence should have been:

> But still **we** need to improve **ourselves** mentally, financially & emotionally.

Comment: Agreed.  It *can* refer to women, but if that was the case the speaker would have instead said "but **you women** ..." .plus it requires an additional word like "also" to flow sensibly.  Logically the speaker is most likely talking directly to the men in the audience.